I am using an intel based imac and I think that I'm missing the proper drivers
my imac is from 2011 and I fear that I'm not getting the performance that I should so if someone could point me in the direction of any drivers that I may be missing or need to replace and how to install them that would be great

What exactly do you mean by not getting the performance that I should?

Please add more details about your system specification (processor, RAM, graphics card, iMac model)

You can find graphics drivers (e.g. NVidia) and WiFi drivers (if necessary) at "Additional drivers". The driver for the intel CPU is already provided by Linux.
Unless you are having performance issues related to graphics, it may help to switch to a lighter flavor of Ubuntu, like Ubuntu MATE.
In many cases, old computers (including iMacs) become slow due to old HDD. If you can replace it to a SSD it would be incredibly fast. In some iMacs, replacing the hard drive is very hard (requires removing the screen), and you can't do much about it.

I suggest adding some additional information about how to find a compatible graphics driver (possibly an old version graphics driver) because this iMac is 13 years old.

@karel I don't think Linux kernel drops driver support even if they are 13 years old. NVidia usually keeps dropping support for older graphics hardware, but they are still supported by the free nouvou driver

@karel I have asked OP about their system specification in a comment. As per this link (https://support.apple.com/en-us/111983), the 2011 iMac has a AMD (not Nvidia) card, which should be supported by the kernel out of the box. We need to know more information to provide any further suggestions about improving performance.
